# How to combine these two complicated queries into one query without union?

Tags: sql, join, union

```
(SELECT posts.id FROM posts 
INNER JOIN discussions ON discussions.post_id = posts.id 
INNER JOIN companies ON discussions.company_id = companies.id 
INNER JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.subscribable_id = companies.id AND subscriptions.subscribable_type = 'Company' 
INNER JOIN users ON subscriptions.user_id = users.id WHERE users.id = 6)

UNION 

(SELECT posts.id FROM posts 
INNER JOIN users users_2 ON posts.analyst_id = users_2.id 
INNER JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.subscribable_id = users_2.id AND subscriptions.subscribable_type = 'User'
INNER JOIN users ON subscriptions.user_id = users.id WHERE users.id = 6)
```

It should be obvious that the last join is the same in both queries.. Just not sure how to "or" together joins.

Comment: what's wrong with using a UNION? (except perhaps the possibility of replacing UNION with UNION ALL)

Comment: Basically to DRY up my SQL query. I've got other manipulations that would be more efficient if this wasn't two queries.

Comment: I would also be willing to 'accept' an answer that pointed to a place that says that joins can't be 'or'ed together.

Comment: Unions can sometimes be combined. The result may or may not be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some joins seem redundant:

- `discussions` could be joined to `subscriptions` directly on the `company_id` column;
- `posts` could be joined to `subscriptions` directly on the `analyst_id` column;
- the last join to `users` in either SELECT is unnecessary as no data is retrieved from that table and the filter (`users.id = 6`) could be re-applied to `subscriptions.user_id`.

So, I would probably rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM posts p
  INNER JOIN discussions d ON d.post_id = p.id
  INNER JOIN subscription s
    ON s.subscribable_type = 'Company' AND s.subscribable_id = d.company_id
    OR s.subscribable_type = 'User'    AND s.subscribable_id = p.analyst_id
WHERE s.user_id = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but give this a try.  Let me know if it works.

```
select posts.id
from posts
inner join discussions
on discussions.post_id = posts.id
inner join companies
on discussions.company_id = companies.id
inner join subscriptions
on subscriptions.subcribable_id = companies.id
inner join users
on subscriptions.user_id = users.id
or users.id = posts.analysis_id
where subscriptions.subscribable_type in ('Company', 'User')
and users.id = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are differences I'm overlooking but if you just want the post if it's in the first or second without using a UNION then:

```
SELECT posts.id FROM posts
where posts.id IN 
(
SELECT posts.id FROM posts
INNER JOIN discussions ON discussions.post_id = posts.id 
INNER JOIN companies ON discussions.company_id = companies.id 
INNER JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.subscribable_id = companies.id AND subscriptions.subscribable_type = 'Company' 
INNER JOIN users ON subscriptions.user_id = users.id WHERE users.id = 6
)
or
posts.id IN 
(
SELECT posts.id FROM posts 
INNER JOIN users users_2 ON posts.analyst_id = users_2.id 
INNER JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.subscribable_id = users_2.id AND subscriptions.subscribable_type = 'User'
INNER JOIN users ON subscriptions.user_id = users.id WHERE users.id = 6
)
```

Comment: The original query would not contain duplicates either, as UNION implies DISTINCT (unlike UNION ALL).

Comment: You're right, never knew UNION implied distinct: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html